# Reachability API not sensing WiFi switch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wifi, reachability

I am using the reachability sample in my project to test the network connectivity.
I am using ReachabilityForInternetConnection.
The callback gets called most of the times during WiFi switch but it does not get called sometimes in case of few WiFi switches. So I started notifier for WIFi reachability as well. But still the callback does not get called for the WiFi switch sometimes.
What should I do so that the WiFi switch event gets called all times?
I was pointed to implenting a timer to sense the events but I think if apple has a callback mechanism; polling is an efficient option and also should not become a cause for app rejection.
Please let me know if I am missing something.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not found any solution as yet but it does happen sporadically.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Any solution?